# CSS, игнорирование отступов родителя

Tags: css, bootstrap

Добрый день,

Есть div с отступами (адаптив) в нем один из divов нужно заставить игнорировать отступы вышеупомянутого div и быть во всю ширину окна при этом оставаясь адаптивным. Как это реализовать? Используется bootstrap, структуру шаблона менять запретили.

Спасибо.

Comment: покажите код (минимальная длина комментариев 15 символов)

Comment: <div id="a" style="margin:0 auto;  background-color:#CCC; width:200px">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud
 <div id="b" style="background-color:#f00">
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis distinctio ratione illum, possimus vitae iste modi doloremque recusandae pariatur totam necessitatibus dolor tempora
 </div>
</div>

Comment: Лучше добавить код в сам вопрос и в более читабельном виде.

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь что средствами css можно посчитать резиновый отступ родителя.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у окна нет вертикального скролла, то можно так:

```css
section {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #CCC;
  width:200px;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #f00;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<section>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <div> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis distinctio ratione illum, possimus vitae iste modi doloremque recusandae pariatur totam necessitatibus dolor tempora </div> 
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Нормально взаимодействует со скроллом, но не занимает места в контейнере.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative;
}

section {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #CCC;
  width: 200px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  <div> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis distinctio ratione illum, possimus vitae iste modi doloremque recusandae pariatur totam necessitatibus dolor tempora </div>
</section>
```